# Two way data binding between controller and external directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

## My setup:

Imagine a *controller* for a shopping cart:

```
app.controller('CartCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
        {
            id:0,
            title:'article1'
        },
        {
            id:1,
            title:'article2'
        }
    ];

    $scope.countItems = function(){
        var num = 0;
        for(var i in $scope.data){
            num++
        }
        return num;
    } 
});
```

It's used somewhere on the page:

```
<ul ng-controller="CartCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="item in data">{{item.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

*Somewhere else* I'd like to display the number of items in my cart:

```
<div cart-item-number>{{countItems()}}</div>
```

To connect the data I use a *directive*:

```
app.directive('cartItemNumber', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'CartCtrl'
    };
});
```

## My Question:

*On page load the correct number is displayed*. However if I remove or add an item from/to the data-object the *cart-item-number does not update*.

**How can I solve this issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the `ng-controller="CartCtrl"` and `controller: 'CartCtrl'` are two different objects. In the directive declaration you specify the controller for **the directive**. When your application starts they both are initialized with the same data, therefore it **seems** to work consistently.

If you want to display the number of items within the scope of `CartCtrl` than you do not need to use a directive (btw. it would be better to just use `data.length`). If your intention is to display it outside of the scope than you have to create some form of communication.
Or at least move your `cart` higher in the hierarchy of scopes -- for sure on the `$rootScope` it would be visible everywhere in you application (unless you are using an `isolated scope`).

Answer (score 2):

First off, the reason is because your are not working on the same scope. Consider the following example:

```
<body>
  <ul ng-controller="CartCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="item in data">{{item.title}}</li>
  </ul>
  <div cart-item-number>{{countItems()}}</div>
</body>
```

The directive registers on RootScope, while ngController is a child scope. So you effectively ends up with two copies of data. I suggest you use the [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) Chrome plugin to visualize the above scopes and models.

Moving ng-controller in the above example to body you will see expected behavior.

**However**, the way you are using controllers is considered bad practice. The sole purpose of a directive controller is to expose an API to other directives, for directive to directive communication. Where "normal" controllers (used in ngController and routes) are used to augment scope and add behavior to the scope object.

If you need to communicate between a "normal" controller and a directive you should either use a mediator service (let both your controller and directive depend on this service), or use $scope events like $scope.$broadcast and $scope.$emit to communicate between them. This decouples your controllers from directives and allows for re-usable components and easy tests.